# Recuperar campo relacionado en otra tabla

Tags: python, django

Estoy usando django 1.10, con python 3.5 en Windows 8.1. Tengo una base de datos que considera campos sobre un elemento (Trabajo) , en otra tabla (Modalidad) tengo el identificador y la descripción de ésta Modalidad, pero en Trabajo, sólo tengo guardado el valor de la modalidad.

Ya tengo el modelo que me despliega los elementos de Trabajo, pero me muestra el valor de Modalidad, cuando yo quiero ver la descripción. Los modelos son:

```
class Modalidad(models.Model):
    MODALIDAD_CHOICES = (
        ('1', 'PechaKucha'),
        ('2', 'Cartel'),
    )
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices= MODALIDAD_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.descripcion

class Trabajo(models.Model):
    no_trabajo = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    modalidad = models.ForeignKey(Modalidad)
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    area_tematica = models.ForeignKey(AreaTematica)
    autores = models.ManyToManyField(Autor)
    facultad = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    institucion = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    pais = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

la vista que uso es la siguiente:

```
from trabajo.models import Trabajo    

def carga_trabajos(request):
        lista_trabajos = Trabajo.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'carga_trabajos.html', {'lista_trabajos' : lista_trabajos})
```

y en el documento html, uso una tabla para mostrar la lista:

```
<tbody>
       {% for dato in lista_trabajos %}
       <tr>
           <td>{{ dato.no_trabajo }}</td>
           <td>{{ dato.titulo }}</td>
           <td>{{ dato.modalidad }}</td>
           <td>{{ dato.facultad }}</td>
           <td>{{ dato.institucion }}</td>
           <td>{{ dato.pais }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
 </tbody>
```

Se que en la vista tendría que ajustar el código para incluir `Modalidad.descripcion` para que lo pueda incluir en la tabla.

Y como podrán ver, de la misma forma tengo que ajusta el código para recuperar `Area_tematica.descripcion` y visualizarla en mi tabla, pero con la ayuda de la primera, ya podría resolver la segunda.

Les agradezco mucho su apoyo. Estoy muy emocionado usando django ya que con este framework se me está aclarando mucho la manera de trabajar para el desarrollo de aplicaciones.

Reciban todos un saludo.
Gustavo.

Answer (score 2):

Podrias crear una vista en la base de datos a la que se esta conectado Django que ya tenga el join ya hecho entre las tablas y mostrarlo directamente, no se con que base estaras trabajando pero si es una relacional por ejemplo podrias correr algo asi en la base:

```
CREATE VIEW [Trabajo_Modalidad]
AS
SELECT    no_trabajo, titulo, modalidad_descricpcion, facultad, institucion, pais
FROM       trabajo inner join modalidad 
    on trabajo.modalidad_id=modalidad.modalidad_id
```

Considerando que trabajo tiene los campos que muestras en el doc html, y la tabla modalidad tiene los campos (modalidad_id,modalidad_descripcion)

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada, considera la necesidad de tener un modelo que tiene solo dos opciones fijas. No parece tan eficiente tener una tabla en la base de datos y hacer consultas relacionadas si estas bien pueden ser opciones estáticas.

Mira, este ejemplo:

```
FOO = 1
BOO = 2

MODALIDADES =(
    (FOO, 'PechaKucha'),
    (BOO, 'Cartel'),
)

class Trabajo(models.Model):
    no_trabajo = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    modalidad = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=MODALIDADES)
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    area_tematica = models.ForeignKey(AreaTematica)
    autores = models.ManyToManyField(Autor)
    facultad = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    institucion = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    pais = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

Ahora bien, lo que intentas hacer se se resuelve con el método `Modelo.get__FOO__display()` que Django proporciona para cada elemento en un campo con opciones `choices`, donde `FOO` es el nombre del campo y el resultado es el valor *legible* de la opción seleccionada.

En tu ejemplo, sería `Trabajo.:

```
<tbody>
  {% for dato in lista_trabajos %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ dato.no_trabajo }}</td>
    <td>{{ dato.titulo }}</td>
    <td>{{ dato.get_modalidad_display }}</td>
    <td>{{ dato.facultad }}</td>
    <td>{{ dato.institucion }}</td>
    <td>{{ dato.pais }}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

La documentación de Django cuenta con ejemplo en este mismo sentido: [Model.get_FOO_display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#extra-instance-methods).

Comment: Muy amables por su apoyo, me funcionó el usar el `Model.get_FOO_display()` aunque seguiré revisando la manera de resolverlo cuando hay la relación entre tablas, ya que por ejemplo en la tabla `trabajo.area_tematica` tengo al menos 17 valores, y éstos varian de acuerdo a la selección que hace el usuario.

Nuevamente, muchas gracias por su orientación, tiempo y paciencia!

Comment: Recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta que resolvió tu problema.